# Submanifold associated to blow up.

Tags: differential-geometry, blowup

I 'm trying to understand the classical blow up given by
$$X=\{(x,[y])\in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{P}_N / \hspace{0.2cm} \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \hspace{0.3cm} \text{such that} \hspace{0.3cm} x=\lambda y \} $$ and
$$\Pi_X: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \hspace{0.4cm} \text{the first projection restricted to X}$$

I have proved that $\Pi^{-1}(\{0\})= \{0\}\times \mathbb{P}_N \subset X$ and that $\Pi_{X\setminus (\{0\}\times \mathbb{P}_N)}$ is homeomorphism (in fact diffeomorphism). But I realized I should also proved that $X$  is a submanifold of the manifold $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{P}_N$.

My question is: how to do it? If $X$ were an open subset it would be easy, just cutting the charts of $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{P}_N $ with $X$, but $X$ is not open (in fact it is closed). I consider cutting the charts of $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{P}_N$  with $X$, but if I did it well, the result is not charts for $X$, because the cut sets of the charts are not homeomorphic to open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then I thought using $\Pi$ for building charts in $X$, but the $\Pi$ is not a homeomorphism if the set $\{0\}\times \mathbb{P}_N$ (which is closed in $X$) is considered in its domain.

Comment: You should state explicitly that $n=N+1$ or, preferably, get rid of $n$ altogether, which I did in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cover $X$ by the open subsets $U_i=\{y_i \neq 0\}\subset X$ and show that $X\cap U_i\subset U_i$ is a submanifold.

**Explicitly:**

For $i=0$, say, we have the identification $U_0=\mathbb R^{N+1}\times \mathbb R^N$ where in that identification  $(y_1,\cdots,y_N)\in \mathbb R^N$ is identified with $[1:y_1\cdots:y_N]\in \mathbb P^N(\mathbb R)$.
In this set-up  $ X\cap U_0$ consists of the pairs $((x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_N),(y_1,\cdots,y_N))\in \mathbb R^{N+1}\times \mathbb R^N$  such that $x_i=x_0y_i$  for $i=1,\cdots,N$,
so that  $X\cap U_0$ consists of all pairs $$((x_0,x_0y_1,\cdots,x_0y_N),(y_1,\cdots,y_N))\in \mathbb R^{N+1}\times \mathbb R^N$$ These pairs clearly form a submanifold of $\mathbb R^{N+1}\times \mathbb R^N$, parametrized by $x_0,y_1,\cdots,y_N$ and isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{N+1}$ .

We have thus proved that   $X\cap U_0$ is a submanifold of $U_0=\mathbb R^{N+1}\times \mathbb R^N$ and a  similar proof shows that $X\cap U_i$ is a submanifold of $U_i$ for $i=1,\cdots,N$.

Comment: I have a doubt about how to prove that the diagonal of $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^m$ $\Delta$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^m$. It is enough to note that $p_1:\Delta \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ (with $p_1$ the first projection) is an homeomorphism being $\mathbb{R}^m$ its image?

Comment: Dear Ted: yes, $\Delta$ is  the graph of the identity mapping $Id:\mathbb R^n \to  \mathbb R^n$ and thus, like any graph, is a submanifold of the product, isomorphic to the source. The projection $p_1:\Delta \to \mathbb R^n$ is indeed a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If you don't mind I'd like to ask another question about the proof. When you said it's sufficient to prove that $X \cap U_i$ is a submanifold $\forall i$, I initially thought it was because if $X \cap U_i$ was submanifold $\forall i$, considering all the charts together one can obtain an atlas for $X$ (knowing that the transition maps are diffeomorphisms). But the open sets of $X \cap U_i$ need not to be open sets in $X$, so how can one see that $X \cap U_i \hspace{0.2cm} \text{submanifold} \Rightarrow$ X \hspace{0.2cm} \text{submanifold}$?

Comment: Dear Ted: oh but yes, the $X\cap U_i$'s  **are**  open in $X$ : you should review the concept of induced topology.

Comment: Right. Well, I had a mistake writing "need not to be open in $X$", I wanted to write "open in $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{P}_N$", but I was wrong, I confused the definition of submanifold. So now I understand the whole proof, thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: You are welcome, ted, and I'm happy that all's well that ends well!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg  I don't know much about differential topology and maybe the answer to the following question is trivial, but how can you identify with the diagonal all the points in X∩Ui? There are infinitely many points [y] such that (0,[y])∈X∩Ui.

Comment: Dear @somebody, you are perfectly right: I messed up my proof which as a result was indeed incorrectly written. I have edited my answer and I hope it is now right. Thanks for your attentive reading.

Comment: You 're welcome, @GeorgesElencwajg, I'm happy to help.